# Why is this line breaking my page?

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress

My `PHP` file starts out with

```
<?php

$tm = new TeamManager();

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var team = <?php echo json_encode($tm->GetWholeTeam()); ?>;
</script>
```

and the rest isn't being read, for reasons unknown. I've narrowed it down to the line `<?php echo json_encode($tm->GetWholeTeam()); ?>` but no errors are showing even if I add

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

to the top of the script. For reference, my `TeamManager` class is defined in

```
<?php

// Gets included in functions.php


final class MySqlInfo
{

    const TEAMTABLENAME = 'mems';
    const PROJSTABLENAME = 'projs';

    public static function getTeamTableName ( )
    {
        return self::TEAMTABLENAME;
    }

    public static function getProjectsTableName ( )
    {
        return self::PROJSTABLENAME;
    }
}

final class MethodResult
{

    public $succeeded; 
    public $message; 

    public function MethodResult ( $succeededInit = NULL, $messageInit = NULL )
    {
        $this->$succeeded = $succeededInit;
        $this->$message = $messageInit;
    }   

}

final class TeamMember 
{
    public $name; // team member name
    public $title; // team member title
    public $bio; // team member bio
    public $sord; // team member sort order
    public $picfn; // team member profile picture file name

    public function TeamMember ( $name_init, $title_init, $bio_init, $sord_init, $picfn_init )
    {
        $this->name = $name_init; 
        $this->title = $title_init;
        $this->bio = $bio_init;
        $this->sord = $sord_init;
        $this->picfn = $picfn_init;
    }
}

final class TeamManager
{

    public function TeamManager ( )
    {
        // ....
    }

    public function addMember ( TeamMember $M )
    {

        $q = "INSERT INTO " . MySqlInfo::TEAMTABLENAME . " (" . implode( ',', array($M->name, $M->title, $M->bio, $M->sord, $M->picfn) ) . ") VALUES ('" . implode('\',\'', array($_POST['fullname'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['bio'], $_POST['sord'], $targetFileName)) . "')";
        // ^ query for inserting member M to the database

        if (!$wpdb->query($q))
        {
            return new MethodResult(false, 'Query to insert new team member failed');
        }
        // else
        return new MethodResult(true, 'Successfully added new member' . $M->name);
    }

    public function getWholeTeam ( )
    {
        $q = "SELECT name,title,bio,sord,picfn FROM " . MySqlInfo::TEAMTABLENAME;
        $teamRows = $wpdb->query($q);
        return $teamRows; 
    }
}

?>
```

but I am not getting any errors on that page either. I've also run everything through an online `PHP` validator and do not get any errors. What gives?

Comment: This seems to be Javascript error rather than a PHP error. After your page is loaded, have a look at the source. I suspect `var team` is initialised wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope:

```
    $teamRows = $wpdb->query($q);
                ^^^^^
```

That is undefined within your getWholeTeam() method (and in all the methods that use it, in fact) You need a

```
 global $wpdb;
```

in there.

You should have AT LEAST gotten an undefined variable warning on `$wpdb` and a fatal error for "calling member function on non-object". That suggests you've got all debug options turned off: you need to enable `error_logging` and `display_errors` when you're debugging. They should never be off in the first place on a devel system.

Comment: But what I have in `functions.php` is `global $wpdb;
require_once 'classes.php';` which means that `$wpdb` is defined by the time that `classes.php` is "pasted" into `functions.php` -- right?

Comment: doesn't matter. it's not defined in that method. you have to declare the globalness of a variable in every function/method you're using it in. There is no way for usercode to create a new superglobal that's automatically everywhere, like $_GET/_POST

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$tm = new TeamManager();

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var team = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($tm->GetWholeTeam()); ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: exactly how does this change anything? json IS javascript. dumping json_encode output into a variable assignment is perfectly valid... and would in fact work even in older browsers that DON'T have direct JSON.* support.